# If the weights of all branches in the graph were equal to 1, what would Dijkstra's algorithm return as the shortest paths from a given node?

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, shortest-path, dijkstra

If there exists a weighted graph G, and all weights are 1, what would Dijkstra's algorithm return as the shortest paths from a given node?

Comment: A shortest path !

Comment: You tagged the correct answer...

Comment: When we say "shortest path" we mean "shortest path between two nodes". Not just "from a given node" but "from a given node to another given node".

Comment: I said shortest paths, so I meant from a given node to all nodes in a graph

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you suggesting that Dijkstra's algorithm would break down when all weights are 1? Do you have a graph for which the algorithm behaves unexpectedly?

Answer (score 0):

A correct implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm will return, for every node, the 'predecessor' node.  If you follow the predecessor nodes in sequence you will get back to the given node on a path that goes over the fewest number of connections.